# What is a simple, minimal example of a JSON payment paypal definition?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, paypal, payment

I am looking for a simple JSON example of a paypal definition for a donation. This does not seem to be covered in PayPal docs. It needs a simple parameter for a specific date for the payment to be made, and a option for it to be recurring on this date annually. I have tried the following , but it does not allow for a payment date or recurring. What needs adding?

```
var create_payment_json = {
    "intent": "sale",
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "paypal"
    },
    "redirect_urls": {
        "return_url": "http://return.url",
        "cancel_url": "http://cancel.url"
    },
    "transactions": [{
        "item_list": {
            "items": [{
                "name": "item",
                "sku": "item",
                "price": "1.00",
                "currency": "USD",
                "quantity": 1
            }]
        },
        "amount": {
            "currency": "USD",
            "total": "1.00"
        },
        "description": "This is the payment description."
    }]
};
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You may find the decent examples along with Json in [Paypal official documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payments/paypal-payments).

Below is the example based on official [PayPal payment page](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payments/paypal-payments/#create-paypal-payment).

```
curl -v -X POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment \
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token" \
-d '{
  "intent": "sale",
  "payer": {
    "payment_method": "paypal"
  },
  "transactions": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "total": "30.11",
        "currency": "USD",
        "details": {
          "subtotal": "30.00",
          "tax": "0.07",
          "shipping": "0.03",
          "handling_fee": "1.00",
          "shipping_discount": "-1.00",
          "insurance": "0.01"
        }
      },
      "description": "This is the payment transaction description.",
      "custom": "EBAY_EMS_SOMENUMBER",
      "invoice_number": "INV000001",
      "payment_options": {
        "allowed_payment_method": "INSTANT_FUNDING_SOURCE"
      },
      "soft_descriptor": "ECHI5786786",
      "item_list": {
        "items": [
          {
            "name": "dontation",
            "description": "dontation",
            "quantity": "1",
            "price": "10",
            "tax": "0.00",
            "sku": "1",
            "currency": "USD"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "note_to_payer": "Thankyour for your donation.",
  "redirect_urls": {
    "return_url": "https://example.com",
    "cancel_url": "https://example.com"
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not involve either the recurring or specific date, and that's what I can't find

Answer (score 1):

There is no such parameter to control whether a payment is recurring or will be *captured or charged* at a later time in the future that way.

In order to achieve semblance of what's possible in *Stripe*, you need to work different.

**For recurring billing**,

- [create a billing plan featuring recurring payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/quickstart/create-billing-plan/#define-the-billing-plan-object).
- create a billing agreement for the customer to that *billing plan*. [Executing this agreement](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/quickstart/create-billing-agreement/#execute-billing-agreement) sets the recurring billing process in motion.

**For [later capture](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/quickstart/capture-payment/)**,

- create a payment of type authorization
- store the *capture URL* returned in the response.

  **Note that** this *capture URL* is live for a certain period of time. This *capture url* can be refreshed just one time by re-authorizing payment if the payment isn't captured within that period of time.

  Sadly, *Paypal* doesn't provide an API to automatically capture payment at a later time you can specify like *Stripe* does it. You have the responsibility to ensure that.

  However, there are service integrations that extend Paypal to provide this functionality, *see [Braintree Vault for Paypal](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/vault/javascript/v3)*).